# Duplicated Content when Joining Tables

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have two tables that I have joined in my SQL command:

```
$resArtistList = mysql_query("SELECT c_3.mus_artist.*, c_3.mus_track.* FROM c_3.mus_artist  INNER JOIN c_3.mus_track ON c_3.mus_artist.artistId=c_3.mus_track.trackArtistId  WHERE artistName LIKE '".iSql($_GET['artist-letter'])."%' OR artistName LIKE 'The ".iSql($_GET['artist-letter'])."%' ORDER BY artistName", $dataLink) or die(mysql_error());
```

It works fine apart from there is duplicated content being displayed.  I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c_3.mus_artist.*, c_3.mus_track.*)
```

However that just gives this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM c_3.mus_artist INNER JOIN c_3.mus_track ON c_3.mus_artist.artistId=c_3.' at line 1

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I assume by 'duplicated content' you mean 'duplicate rows/records', correct? Try removing `(` and `)` from `SELECT DISTINCT(c_3.mus_artist.*, c_3.mus_track.*)`

Comment: Can you give example output and the output you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
GROUP BY artistName
```

just before the ORDER BY